# How can I center this "Get Started "button below this title?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made this "Get Started" button. I want to put it below the title "All memories in one film". I tried aligning it, but it won't work.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 50vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(58, 58, 58, 0.75)), url(4kcamera.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    
}


.logo{
    float: left;
    padding: 0 30px;
    margin-left: 55px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    width: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 90px;
    padding: 0 31px;
}

ul{
    margin-left: 840px;
}

ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
}

ul li a:hover {
    color: rgb(102, 151, 241);
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

#text{
    transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 60px;
}

#button1{
    background-color: rgb(30, 109, 255); 
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px 50px;
    color: white;
    padding: 35px;
    margin: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>PRODUX NA</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
            <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "reset.css"/>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@600&family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
        <body>
            <nav>
                <a href="index.html">
                    <img class="logo" src="1 NA.png" width="50" height="50">
                </a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="about.html">About Me</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div id="text">

            </div>    
            
            <script type = "text/javascript">
                var i = 0,text;
                text = "All your favorite memories in one film."
                
                function typing(){
                    if(i < text.length){
                        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += text.charAt(i);
                        i++
                        setTimeout(typing, 50);
                    }
                }
                typing();
            </script>
            <div class="container">
                <button id="button1">Get Started</button>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

The button is below the javascript function. The id is "button1" and the container's id is just "container". As you can see in the CSS file, I used the text-align command.

In addition, I also tried justifying the content to the center and aligning all the items to the center below the title (uses Javascript function). Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing my best to keep the changes true to your project without restructuring your html. Depending on how you are using this, there are better ways to structure your html.

The first thing I did was create a container for the text and button to be nested inside. Then I moved both your text div, and your container div with the button inside this other container. Then, I moved many of your absolute positioning to the `#textAndButtonContainer` from your `#text` styling. Then, I used `display: flex` to allow flexbox styling / centering as I find it is the easiest way to center things.

Hopefully this helps!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(58, 58, 58, 0.75)), url(4kcamera.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  position: fixed;

}


.logo{
  float: left;
  padding: 0 30px;
  margin-left: 55px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

ul li{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 90px;
  padding: 0 31px;
}

ul{
  margin-left: 840px;
}

ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: rgb(102, 151, 241);
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

#text{
  transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 60px;
}

#textAndButtonContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#button1{
  background-color: rgb(30, 109, 255);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px 50px;
  color: white;
  padding: 35px;
  margin: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>PRODUX NA</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
            <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "reset.css"/>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@600&family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
        <body>
            <nav>
                <a href="index.html">
                    <img class="logo" src="1 NA.png" width="50" height="50">
                </a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="about.html">About Me</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div id="textAndButtonContainer">
              <div id="text">

              </div>
              <div class="container">
                  <button id="button1">Get Started</button>
              </div>
            </div>

            <script type = "text/javascript">
                var i = 0,text;
                text = "All your favorite memories in one film."

                function typing(){
                    if(i < text.length){
                        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += text.charAt(i);
                        i++
                        setTimeout(typing, 50);
                    }
                }
                typing();
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is the text which has the position `absolute`. To position the button below the text, the container which is holding the button must also be positioned `absolute`. This will in turn align the button as well.

Add this to the style:

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25px;/*give enough space to the text above*/
    left: 50%;/*to horizontally center it*/
    transform: translateX(-50%);/*to horizontally center it*/
}
```

This positions the button at the bottom of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the button's parent div to have a class of `text-center`, and add a `.text-center` to your CSS.

So you would have HTML:

```
<div class="text-center">
     <button id="button1">Get Started</button>
</div>
```

And for your CSS:

```
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```